# How to connect SharePoint online list to insert data from out side the SharePoint platform using

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, graph-api

We have a requirement to push data from the external application into the SharePoint online list.
Please guide me on the steps and specifically the how the authentication should happen from external application to SP Online.

Kindly guide, whether we can use SP exposed REST api end points/any web service we need to write/ Graph API.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are following ways to do so and you can use based on your external application support

**1. SharePoint REST API**

Official Documentation - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

Demo - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/

**2. Microsoft Graph API**

Official Documentation - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0

**3. SharePoint Web Service (Classic Approach - Does not support Modern Authentication)**

Demo using JavaScript - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36620.crud-on-list-items-using-web-services-and-jquery-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1.aspx

**4. CSOM (C# - If you application uses it)**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code

Hope it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get started with Business Data Connectivity Model is to:
Run Microsoft SharePoint Designer.
Connect to the destination site.
Select External Content Types from the Navigation pane.
Select the External Content Type button from the External Content Types ribbon menu.

Regards,
Peter